# (Spacemacs) pressing SPC to replace a match during query-replace does not work

Tags: spacemacs, query-replace

(Spacemacs)

`M-%` starts `query-replace`, and when a match is found, `?` shows help, which indicates:

> Type Space or ‘y’ to replace one match, Delete or ‘n’ to skip to next,

However, pressing `Space` simply inserts a space rather than replacing text (`y` still works). As a long time emacs user, this is a frustrating loss of functionality. Any suggestions on how it can be reinstituted?

Comment: Just to be sure... Do you see the same thing when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) - however that might be done with Spacemacs? If not, the bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a recent Spacemacs change of the Emacs defaults. Either set dotspacemacs-use-SPC-as-y to t in your dotspacemacs/init

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/init ()
  (setq-default

   ... ;; all the other dospacemacs-* variables 

   ;; Accept SPC as y for prompts if non nil. (default nil)
   dotspacemacs-use-SPC-as-y t))
```

or do (define-key query-replace-map " " 'act) in your dotspacemacs/user-config to return to the classic behavior.

Comment: be sure to add the value for dotspacemacs-use-SPC-as-y inside the setq-default list of the dotspacemacs/init function. I edited the answer to be cleaner